# Sample variance and False Positive Rate

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, standard-error, false-discovery-rate

Consider drawing many samples of size $n$ from a normally distributed population. The standard error associated with a sample is a function of the sample standard deviation. The sample standard deviation is uncorrelated with the sample mean. Therefore, I would intuitively expect a negative correlation between the sample standard deviation and the probability of having a False Positive. Does it seem right?

I failed to address the question analytically so I made it numerically and it seems to confirm my intuition (see below).

**Question**

Knowing the population variance and the significance level...

- what is the expected variance of a sample given that it is a False positive?
- what is the expected variance of a sample given that it is a True Negative?

---

Here is my short script

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)
n = 100
mu = 100
sd = 5
iterations = 10000

RejectNull = c()
sds = c()

######
sqn = sqrt(n)
for (i in 1:iterations)
{
    if (i%%100==0) cat(paste("progression: ", i/iterations, "\n"))
    sample = rnorm(n,mu,sd)
    meanSample = mean(sample)
    sds[i] = sd(sample)
    SE = sds[i]/sqn
    if (meanSample + 1.96*SE < mu | meanSample - 1.96*SE > mu) {RejectNull[i] = TRUE} else  {RejectNull[i] = FALSE}
}
ggplot(data.frame(x=RejectNull, y=sds), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot()

#qqnorm(sds)
mean(RejectNull) # 0.0481
t.test(sds~RejectNull)


    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sds by RejectNull
t = 7.8871, df = 534.58, p-value = 1.753e-14
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.09326578 0.15513335
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
           4.999718            4.875518
```

[image]

Comment: Given that you have bounded the true negatives to a specific (but varying) interval, and have left the false positives unbounded, is it not logical that the unbounded sample will have a higher variance?